# Algorithm for generating hyperexponential distribution

Tags: algorithms, statistics

I need to generate a hyperexponential distribution for my project. I have already implemented a poisson generating algorithm given by Donald Knuth, but I couldn't find an algorithm for generating a hyper exponential random variable.

I am provided with the mean and variance required of the distribution and I need an algorithm which can generate a random variable from this distribution when I execute it.

Comment: Could you explain more about the distribution of numbers?

Comment: I am assuming that you are unfamiliar with hyperexponential distribution. For info on this, refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperexponential_distribution